# SAS- keep only if in list

Tags: database, sas

I have a macro where the user can choose what file to run the macro on. I would like to know if there is a way to keep only one variable from each dataset chosen and only if it appears in my list of variable names.

So for example the user would enter %LET TABLEN=revinfo; where revinfo.sas contains the variable revenue but not income profit or sales. I only want the one variable revenue.

I tried multiple keep statements, but it errors if it tries to keep a variable that is not there.

```
data want;
SET have.&TABLEN;
    KEEP     income;
    KEEP     revenue;
    KEEP     profit;
    KEEP     sales;
RUN;
```

Thanks so much,
KK

Comment: How do you know that `revinfo` has `revenue`, and conversely how do you know that `revenue` is the variable to keep from `revinfo`?

Comment: First step - detail your logic. A diagram or table written down will save you hours of head vs desk.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this, assuming that you are taking care of any input validation separately, or leaving that to your users, is to tell SAS to not to error if you try to keep a variable that isn't there. You can do that by setting `option dkricond = warn;` or `nowarn` rather than the default of `error`.

If you go down this route, I would also advise making a note of the previous setting before you change this option and then changing it back after the rest of your macro has run.